# non-const lvalue reference type _normal_iterator<> cannot bind a temporary of type _normal iterator in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

In the last line of the below code I get an error: 
`non-const lvalue reference type _normal_iterator<> cannot bind a temporary of type _normal iterator` with gcc, but not with Visual studio. Any suggestions why are highly appreciated.

```
struct Hand {
    Hand() = default;
    explicit Hand(std::set<std::string> cards) : cards(std::move(cards)) {}
    auto begin() const { return cards.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return cards.end(); }
};

std::vector<Hand> player_hands(number_players);  // empty container

auto &hand_it = player_hands.begin();
```

Comment: Why do you have the `&` in `auto &hand_it`?

Comment: `auto &hand_it = player_hands.begin();` Did you mean `auto hand_it = player_hands.begin();`? Temporary can't be bound to non-const reference. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: It does work in visual studio. I want to iterate over a vector and change it. Don’t I need a reference for that?

Comment: iterators are 'pointer like' objects, so it is ok to copy it, the reference/pointer to the element gets copied, not the element itself.

Comment: Visual Studio has for a long time allowed lvalue references to bind to temporaries, which is incorrect and dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`begin` does not return a reference. It returns an iterator, which is itself an object, by value. Therefore `player_hands.begin();` is a temporary. Temporaries can not be bound to non-const lvalue references.

What you can do is either of the following:

```
auto hand_it = player_hands.begin(); 

const auto& hand_it = player_hands.begin(); 

auto&& hand_it = player_hands.begin();
```

What you should use is the first case. Although the lifetime of the temporary will be extended in the other two cases, there is no need to use references at all. The second case also limits the usability, because it makes the iterator `const`, making it impossible to e.g. `hand_it++`.

The iterator object itself refers to an element of the container. There is no need for references. A reference to the container element is obtained from the iterator with the indirection operator: `*hand_it`

Visual C++ is non-compliant with the standard in allowing binding of temporaries to non-const lvalue references. You can use the `/permissive-` flag to make it compliant and issue an error message for this code.